# Parallel.ForEach() changes Impersonation Context

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, impersonation, parallel.foreach

Today we deployed our newly created ASP.NET application to the server and soon we realized there was a strange security-related issue which was causing the application to crash. This is an internal application and we use Impersonation to manage how the users access resources. The application however, throws an "Access Denied" exception when the user attemps to access a folder over which they have full control.

The exception was in fact an `AggregateException` and was being thrown in a method which uses `Parallel.ForEach` to enumerate over a list and inside the body, it attempts to access the folder, but at this point the Impersonation Context gets changed and the worker thread runs as the application pool's identity, which doesn't have access to the folder hence the exception.

To confirm this, I looked at the process identity before and inside the body of `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
string before = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
Debug.WriteLine("Before Loop: {0}", before);

Parallel.ForEach(myList, currentItem =>
{
    string inside = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    Debug.WriteLine("Inside Loop: {0} (Worker Thread {1})", inside, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
});
```

When I run the app, this is what gets printed out:

```
Before Loop: MyDomain\ImpersonatedUser

Inside Loop: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (Worker Thread 8)
Inside Loop: MyDomain\ImpersonatedUser (Worker Thread 6)
Inside Loop: MyDomain\ImpersonatedUser (Worker Thread 7)
Inside Loop: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (Worker Thread 9)
Inside Loop: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (Worker Thread 10)
Inside Loop: MyDomain\ImpersonatedUser (Worker Thread 7)
Inside Loop: MyDomain\ImpersonatedUser (Worker Thread 6)
Inside Loop: MyDomain\ImpersonatedUser (Worker Thread 7)
```

As  you can see, some threads are running as the impersonated identity and some as the application pool (in this case, `LocalSystem`) and there doesn't seem to be a pattern. The previous frame in the `Call Stack` window also goes to the unmanaged `kernel32.dll`, which makes me think CLR isn't validating the context before delegating it to the OS.

Any idea why this is happening? Is that a known issue/bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike the `Task` class, `Parallel` doesn't seem to be capturing the `ExecutionContext` you're currently running on (which in turns captures the `SecurityContext` which holds the `WindowsIdentity`). It uses the one avaliable inside the current Thread.

You have to explicitly capture the desired context:

```
IntPtr token = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token;

Parallel.ForEach(myList, currentItem =>
{
   using (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(token))
   {
      string inside = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
      Debug.WriteLine("Inside Loop: {0} (Worker Thread {1})", inside, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
   }
});
```

Comment: But why it indeed doesn't seem to be a pattern?

Comment: Im not too sure. I've previously seen questions regarding this manner. Seems like a feature that *should* be implemented as it is the *expected* behavior.

Comment: Yes I'm using `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate()` as a workaround but I still don't understand why there's a discrepancy among threads. If the `SecurityContext` isn't being captured, how come some of the threads still run as the impersonated identity? I feel like there's more to this.

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering the same: context is either captured always or it isn't always. But actually it's *sometimes*.

Comment: I think `Parallel` also uses the current executing thread as part of its thread pool. Thats why we *sometimes* see the right identity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# extension method to make this a little easier...

```
public static ParallelLoopResult ParallelForEach<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IPrincipal principal, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action<TSource> body)
        {
            return Parallel.ForEach(source, parallelOptions, (source) =>
            {
                if (!CurrentUser.Instance.IsAuthenticated)
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                body(source);
            });
        }
```

And here is how you call it:

```
puppies.ParallelForEach(
                    CurrentUser.Instance.Principal,
                    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 },
                    (puppy) => PetAnimal(puppy)
                );
```

Answer (score -2):

The whole Impersonation concept in Windows is a per thread concept. 
You see, when a new thread is created, it inherits the process' privileges token.
But threads, *unlike* processes, also have an impersonation token. When you call WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(token) you set the impersonation token on the *calling thread*.

Also when you call Impersonate you set the thread's primary token pointer to point to the impersonation token instead of the process' primary token, which is the default.

A little bit more understanding and knowledge in the WinAPI would lead you to know that what happened in your service *is* the expected behavior.

Comment: And a little less snark makes the world a better place, and should be the expected behaviour.